# Insert Array to Array Collection without looping

Tags: php

I have two array..

**Array 1**

```
$arr1 = array(
    'task' => 'delete'
)
```

**Array 2**

```
$arr2 = array(
            array(
                'id'    => '1', 
                'type'  => 'post',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => '2', 
                'type'  => 'category',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => '1', 
                'type'  => 'tag',
            ),
        );
```

How I insert Array 1 to all Array 2 collection, so the results is.

```
$arr2 = array(
            array(
                'id'    => '1',
                'task' => 'delete',
                'type'  => 'post',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => '2', 
                'task' => 'delete',
                'type'  => 'category',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => '1', 
                'task' => 'delete',
                'type'  => 'tag',
            ),
        );
```

I can be easily to get the results by using looping, but I want to achieve it not using looping.
Any suggestion ?
Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to push arraay1 in array2 all indexes, you can use the array_walk with a combination of array merge, you can see below code for instance

```
    <?php

   $array1 = array(
    'task' => 'delete',
    'before' =>'test'
);


    $array2=array(
                array(
                    'id'    => '1', 
                    'type'  => 'post',
                ),
                array(
                    'id'    => '2', 
                    'type'  => 'category',
                ),
                array(
                    'id'    => '1', 
                    'type'  => 'tag',
                ),
            );


    array_walk($array2, function(&$newarray) use ($array1) {
        $newarray = array_merge($newarray, $array1);
    });

print_r($array2);

?>
```

array_walk -Apply a user supplied function to every member of an array while array_merge, Merge two arrays into one array

Result

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [type] => post [task] => delete [before] => test ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [type] => category [task] => delete [before] => test )
[2] => Array ( [id] => 1 [type] => tag [task] => delete [before] => test ) )
```

Git Hub

https://github.com/fahadpatel/insert-array-into-array-without-loop

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m1i6-587x)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map). It's looping behind the scenes, though (no real way around it), but at least you don't have to do it yourself:

```
$arr3 = array_map(static function ($entry) use ($arr1) {
  return $entry + $arr1;
}, $arr2);
```

PHP 7.4 version:

```
$arr3 = array_map(static fn($entry) => $entry + $arr1, $arr2);
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/2u2SR**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_walk` to skip writing the loop.

```
$arr1 = array(
    'task' => 'delete'
);

$arr2 = array(
            array(
                'id'    => '1', 
                'type'  => 'post',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => '2', 
                'type'  => 'category',
            ),
            array(
                'id'    => '1', 
                'type'  => 'tag',
            ),
        );

array_walk($arr2, function(&$item) use ($arr1) {
    $item = array_merge($item, $arr1);
});
```

You can see the documentation for `array_walk` [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).